# Is it possible to create an SPA with shareable URLs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to create a web app with shareable links and pages rendered from the server that don't refresh when changing URLs?

For example, I'm thinking of having the user be able to view site.com/game/1 and have the server render some React template for the game if game 1 exists. I also want this url to be viewable without having to use a link from the homepage or other page first, and ideally have the page not refresh. Is any of this possible? If it is, can it be done with React? Can it be done without SSR?

Comment: That's kind of multiple broad questions into one. The quick answer is yes, it's possible, but how really depends on the stack you chose, where you want it hosted, etc. The solution I'm thinking is [JAMStack](https://jamstack.org/), which is, put simply, a static export. Some React frameworks offer this possibility out of the box, like Gatsby and Next.js, but it has its limitations.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Well, for example, could I serve the templates to their appropriate routes using express? Or would that force page refreshes?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, look at what is available already, try it, and learn at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a web app with shareable links and pages rendered from the server that don't refresh when changing URLs?

With [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), you can create an SPA with routing and each page can have its own URL and it's own template(layout) completely different from other pages. Gatsby uses React for rendering the pages.

Comment: With Gatsby, can I have some sort of conditional rendering where, for example, if I get a request for /games/game1 and the server sees that the game has ended, it returns an error page, and otherwise render the game page if it exists?